# ajax request is being sent to PHP to do some maintaining, but errors because it doesnt like php tag?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX request to pings the server, and the URL but returns an error because it doesnt like the '<' as the open tag for the php script.

AJAX script.

```
 $.ajax({
url: "data.php",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({"data":transaction}),
dataType: "json",
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert("success");
    currentProcesses -= 1;
    $("<span>").html("Ajax Call Complete.  Releasing lock for process").appendTo($(body));
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("error with ajax call "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
}
 });
```

php script

```
 <?php
   $win = $_POST['data'];
 ?>
```

Am I using the wrong flag settings for the AJAX call?

Comment: What happens if you open data.php in the browser?  It sounds like the server is not parsing the php but returning it as text.

Comment: @Archer when i run the php file by itself, it processes it.  It just errors because it is looking for an undefined index in that line of code i posted as a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of your POST request is encoded as application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You aren't doing anything to make the request say that the data is encoded in JSON and you aren't doing anything in PHP to try to parse JSON.

As a result, PHP fails to populate `$_POST`, because the data is in the wrong format.

The solution is: Don't send JSON. Just give the data property an object as its value, and jQuery will serialise it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded data for you.

```
data:  { "data": transaction },
```

(Assuming that `transaction` is not a complex data type (like an array or object).

Additionally, the `body` variable is `undefined`. You should either use a string (to make it a selector: `"body"`) or pass the body element directly: `document.body`.

Comment: in the sample i have, transaction is an int......   between the value of 0 and 99,999

Comment: @Fallenreaper — That's fine that. That's a simple data type, so you have no need to do any kind of complex serialisation of the data.

Comment: should i change contentType to what you have?  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: The default value of `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the most sensible format to send the data you have in. Don't touch it.

Comment: ahh perfect! I forgot if i had to set it.  Other then that, what should i do with $(body) as that isnt a defined object?  just put it in quotes as it is a tag?   $("body")

Comment: As I said. Either pass in a selector (a *string* containing the text `body`) or get a reference to the body element (`document.body`, `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`, etc) and pass that directly).

Answer (score 0):

Is it choking on what it's receiveing? Try this...put an id attribute on your span tag, and reference that.

In the page:

```
<span id="someName">...</span>
```

In your ajax call:

```
$("#someName").html(...
```

Comment: The `appendTo` just needs a valid selector passed to it. No need to go about adding empty elements to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `span` more unique using **class** or **id** like

```
<span id="output"></span>
```

and try this.

```
$("#output").html("Ajax Call Complete.  Releasing lock for process").appendTo($(body));
}
```

Comment: It's a new span. It doesn't need to be identified / selected.